# Laravel paginator overrides select (or specifically ->count() does)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I am building a query, and add a select statement, it will be overridden if I use `->paginate(50)` (because `->paginate()` uses `->count()` that seems to override existing select stakements).

I.e.:

```
$users = User::whereActive(1)->addSelect('some-custom-select-statement')->paginate(10); // wont work. 'some-custom-select-statement' will not be returned
```

Or if I even did:

```
$users = User::whereActive(1)->addSelect('some-custom-select-statement')->having('some-custom-select-statement', '>', 0)->count(); // wont work. 'some-custom-select-statement' will not be returned
```

How do I overcome this? Only solution right now is to skip using paginator.

Answer (score 0):

Does the pagination work when you just have `$users = User::whereActive(1)->paginate(10);`?

When I'm using the `addSelect()` I use it after declaring my query, something similar to:

```
$users = User::whereActive(1);
$users->addSelect('my-custom-stuff')->paginate(5);
```